# Passing array of object from response to body of another request

Tags: postman

I have a API response as below, wherein I need to send the 'JobSalesPersons' array block from the response to another API's calls body (see below body section below).

Response:

```
"Data": {
    "AllowTranslationValue": "No",
    "NumberOfOutstandinPages": 0,
    "JobSalesPersons": [
        {
            "JobSalesPersonId": 5204,
            "SalesPersonId": 769,
            "JobIdentity": 7013,
            "Ownership": 100.00,
            "SalesPersonName": "test",
            "JobName": "PostmanAPIJob_2022-06-02_12_53_09",
            "JobID": "HIP22060007",
            "isShowOwnership": false
        }
    ],
    "JobDescription": "Testing for API1"
}
```

Body:

```
{
    "Attachments": [],
    "AllowPrintSchedule": true,
    "IsPDFConvertible": false,
    "AllowTranslation": false,
    "JobSalesPersons": [
    {
        "JobSalesPersonId": 5204,
        "SalesPersonId": 769,
        "JobIdentity": 7013,
        "Ownership": 100.00,
        "SalesPersonName": "test",
        "JobName": "PostmanAPIJob_2022-06-02_12_53_09",
        "JobID": "HIP22060007",
        "isShowOwnership": false
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the response section I have bolded an array, I want that array to be saved in variable (or any other ways) so that I call that array block to another API calls body (which  I have highlighted in the body section below

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or what errors are you running into?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work for you.

Request 1:

Tab `Tests`

```
pm.environment.set("JobSalesPersons", JSON.stringify(pm.response.json().Data.JobSalesPersons));
```

Request 2:

Tab `Body`

```
{
    "Attachments": [],
    "AllowPrintSchedule": true,
    "IsPDFConvertible": false,
    "AllowTranslation": false,
    "JobSalesPersons": {{JobSalesPersons}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response lucas-nguyen... how can I do the same in Postman Flow

Comment: @StephenJose As far as I know, Postman flow doesn't support this directly. You still need environment variables to pass value from response 1 to request 2.